# Update table for records not existing

Tags: sql-server

1- We have some recors that exists in our "datamart" table but doesn't exists anymore in our source system tables.

2- Therefore, we want to hardcode "Unknown" or 0 values into some of those record's columns (`column1` and `column2` for example)

3- This is our 2 tables beeing involved:

```
Datamart.TableA

SourceSystem.TableB
```

4- We want to `UPDATE` our `Datamart.TableA` table as mentionned above in order to insert "Unknown" or 0 values on the columns of the recors that NO longer exists in our `SourceSystem.TableB`

5- This is how our 2 tables are linked:

```
Datamart.TableA.Enumber = SourceSystem.TableB.Eid
```

and

```
Datamart.TableA.AccountNo = SourceSystem.TableB.AccountID
```

QUESTION:

I sort of have an idea that i will probably need to use a `NOT EXISTS` somewhere in my code as well as

```
Datamart.TableA.Eunmber = SourceSystem.TableB.Eid
```

and

```
Datamart.TableA.AccountNo = SourceSystem.TableB.AccountID
```

But, i'm not quite sure how to formulate all this. Any advice please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXITS` in your `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE Datamart.TableA
SET column1 = 0, column2 = 0    
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM SourceSystem.TableB AS b
                  WHERE Datamart.TableA.Enumber = b.Eid AND 
                        Datamart.TableA.AccountNo = b.AccountID)
```

This will update all records of `TableA` with no related records in `TableB`.

Comment: TESTING THE RESULTS OF THE QUERY:                                      
Hello again, when i run such a query, the sql server task bar (not sure how it's called) in the bottom of the window shows that there are 100 rows beeing updated. Which means that there are 100 records from table A that are no longer in the SOURCE table (B).                                  I now want to prove that the correct amount of records were beeing updated in the table A. SO i go an perform the following query in the table B:

Comment: Select 
TableB.EID 
from TableB 
WHERE TableB.EID in (i hardcode here all the "TableA.Enumber" that were retuned from the first query, which returned 100 rows including some duplicates) 
order by EID;
         
/* Expecting to see that 100 records are displayed but it's not the case and it displays much more, like 30 000) */

Comment: Any hints in order for me to validate that the update query actually did update the correct amount of records ?   Thanks in advance fir anh valuable advice.

Comment: @sanchoniathon The validation you are trying to perform is not correct: it doesn't take into account field `AccountID` which is also used to discover existing records in `TableB`.

Comment: @sanchoniathon This query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Datamart.TableA WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SourceSystem.TableB AS b WHERE Datamart.TableA.Enumber = b.Eid AND Datamart.TableA.AccountNo = b.AccountID)` gets the number of records in `TableA` with no associated records in `TableB`.

Comment: Giorgos, thank you so much for such fast replys. I will include this code in my testing result proof.

Answer (score 1):

```
update DataMart.tableA
set    column1 = 0
from   DataMart.tableA a left join SourceSystem.TableB b on a.ENumber = b.Eid and a.AccountNo = b.AccountId
where  b.Eid is null
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try this and keep you posted !